# How can I pass a variable while using `require` in node.js?

Tags: node.js

In my **app.js** I have below 3 lines.

```
var database = require('./database.js');
var client = database.client
var user = require('./user.js');
```

user.js file looks just like ordinary helper methods. But, it needs interact with database.

**user.js**

```
exports.find = function(id){
  //client.query.....
}
```

Apparently, I want to use `client` inside of the `user.js` file. Is there anyway that I can pass this `client` to the `user.js` file, while I am using `require` method?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
var user = require('./user')(client)
```

This enables you to have client as a parameter in each function in your module
or as module scope variable like this:

```
module.exports = function(client){

 ...

}
```

Answer (score 7):

This question is similar to: [Inheriting through Module.exports in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155493/inheriting-through-module-exports-in-node)

Specifically answering your question:

```
module.client = require('./database.js').client;
var user = require('./user.js');
```

In user.js:

```
exports.find = function(id){
  // you can do:
  // module.parent.client.query.....
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You should just put the same code in user.js

**app.js**

```
var client = require('./database.js').client; // if you need client here at all
var user = require('./user.js');
```

**user.js**

```
var client= require('./database.js').client;
exports.find = function(id){
  //client.query.....
}
```

I don't see any drawbacks by doing it like this...

Comment: Well, wouldn't that create `N` clients, if I have `N` models including the database.js file?

Comment: Take a look here for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794968/in-node-js-am-i-creating-a-new-object-when-require

Answer (score -6):

Why do you use `require`, for scr, no prom use `source`. It's the same as require and we can pass args in this fuction.

```
var x="hello i am you";
console.log(require(x));  //error
console.log(source(x));   //it will run without error
```