# Access variable from another file

Tags: node.js

I have ex1.js and ex2.js. And in ex2.js I want to get variable which one is in ex1.js

I can read the file, but I want to get exactly this var Value.

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var readMe = fs.readFileSync('path', 'utf8');
 console.log(readMe);
```

Comment: console.log() ?

Comment: I just checked is it working or not

Comment: You shouldnt explain the problem on the title. Title are just keywords

Comment: this is sample value of your readMe variable: <Buffer 69 64 2c 70 6c 61 6e 5f 69 64 2c 70 72 69 63 65 2c 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 5f 61 74 2c 61 70 69 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 73 2c 64 61 74 61 2c 63 72 65 64 ... >

Comment: I mean inside of file there are a lot of variables and I want to get one of them and change it

Comment: There are no variables to the return value of readFileSync. It just returns you a buffer and you can do whatever you want with it. It returns you a buffer object which is a child of ArrayBuffer.

Comment: thanks for answer.I didn't know about it. Do you know how can I take the variable from another file and replace it?

Comment: what exactly you want to replace? file content?

Comment: there is the var Url = "https://....." I want to change the value of the Url

Comment: then its a file content.

Comment: yes,can I do it withoud reading the file ?Or how can i do it?

Comment: i don't think you can do it without reading the file. Just read the file modify the content and write it back.

Comment: thanks for answer.I will try to find how can realize it

Comment: Now I am reading the file but how can I take the variable?

Comment: fs.readFile('C:/Users/user/.....js', function(error, buffer)

Comment: Get one thing clear, that is not just text file. That is **code file**. You don't read it like text, you compile it. Use [`require`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146980/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-while-using-require-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are both JavaScript files this is how it is generally done.

```
// in the js2 file
exports.var_js2 = 15;

// in the js1 file
var_js2 = require('./js2').var_js2
```