# Define Config Variables For require() Lib

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a library in NodeJS and it requires some configuration variables
I want to be able to define those variables in the main js file, and be able to use them in the core.js file like so

```
var config1 = "stuff"; 
var config2 = "more stuff;

var db = require('./core.js'); //this file uses config1 and config2
```

Is there any way to do this WITHOUT using `exports.config1` and including the file in core.js?
I'm sorry if this is obvious but I couldn't find anything on google.

**EDIT**
I used a class with constructor

```
var config1 = "stuff"; 
var config2 = "more stuff;

var tt = require('./core.js');
const db = new tt(config1, config2);
```

Comment: @Malice it isnt a duplicate the point is going over your head.

Comment: Sorry, I meesed up with the links. You can certainly use what is said here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146980/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-while-using-require-in-node-js

Comment: You basically need to strucutre your core.js a little differently

Comment: @Malice yeah i found a way, i made a class with constructor

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is define them as global variables.

**main.js**

```
global.config1 = "stuff"; 
global.config2 = "more stuff;
```

Then you can access them in the main.js.

**core.js**

```
console.log(global.config1)
```

Also please note that `global` is deprecated. You'll see the following error.

```
(node:59502) DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'
```

Another thing to note is that you should be cautious with putting variables in the global scope.

Comment: I think you missed the point, i want to define config1 and config2 in main.js

Comment: It's just a matter changing file names. See the updated answer. configs are defined in main.js. They are accesses in core.js