# Passing parameters to Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am using Mocha programatically as described here:

https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically

Very similarly to how the examples are written:

test-runner.js:

```
var Mocha = require('mocha');
var mocha = new Mocha();
mocha.addFile('spec.js');
mocha.run(function() {});
```

Inside the test spec, I am spinning up a headless browser to run the test on a specific url:

spec.js:

```
var Browser = new Browser();
browser.visit(url, function(){});
```

Is there a way to pass the desired url from test-runner.js to spec.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your spec file, you can require a module that contains the configurations for those tests:

```
var url = require('./config.js').url;
describe("blah", function(){
    ...
});
```

This config module could also be set from the initial mocha tests (e.g.):

```
var Mocha = require('mocha');
var mocha = new Mocha();

var config = require('./config.js');
config.setOptions({url:"localhost/testme.html"});

mocha.addFile('spec.js');
mocha.run(function() {});
```

Check out [this related SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794968/in-node-js-am-i-creating-a-new-object-when-require) regarding node modules being singletons.