# How do I initialize two independent objects from same module in node.js/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I am programming some mock server test cases for a program I am working on and have encountered an issue that i am unfamiliar with.

Here is the simple rest server

```
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();

var mock = {};
module.exports = mock;
var resp = '';
mock.init = function(name, port,callback) {
    resp = name;
    server.use(restify.bodyParser({
        mapParams: false
    }));

    server.get('/ping', function(req, res, next) {
        res.send(resp);
    });
    server.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
        callback(undefined,server.url);
    });
};
```

and I try to initialize two servers with:

```
var should = require('should');

var mock1 = '';
var mock2 = '';

describe('mock riak load balancer', function() {
    it('should configure a mock riak node', function(done) {
        mock1 = require('./mock.js');
        mock1.init('mock1', 2222, function(e, r) {
            done();
        });
    });
    it('should configure a second mock riak node', function(done) {
        mock2 = require('./mock.js');
        mock2.init('mock2', 2223, function(e, r) {
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Unfortunately I get a connection refused when I ping mock1, so it's being overwritten by the second call.  Guessing this has something to do with the way Javascript handles scoping, but I am not sure.

I resorted to this: https://gist.github.com/hortinstein/5814537 but I think there has to be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has to do with the way node.js loads modules. node.js caches required modules in your process, which means the mock2 is basically the same object as mock1.

more info:

- [Singleton pattern in nodejs - is it needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179109/singleton-pattern-in-nodejs-is-it-needed)
- [In Node.js, am I creating a new object when  "Require"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794968/in-node-js-am-i-creating-a-new-object-when-require)

Comment: great links, any idea how to better do what I have resorted to here (for my mock code) https://gist.github.com/hortinstein/5814537

Comment: take a look at [rewire](https://npmjs.org/package/rewire), a dependency injection module for creating mocks, which are really mocks